# Set a variable inside a v-for loop on Vue JS to use it in the same loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want things to be like this: :user variable is created and then used as {{user.name}}

```
<li v-for="(id,index) in computedUsersAgeSorter" :user="UsersKeyedObject[id[0]]">{{user.name}}</li>
```

Because UsersKeyedObject {123199:{name:"John",age:23},...} cannot be sorted, I create sorter array as Vue computed(), and iterate through it. Using array-part key, as you can see, looks too complex, so I'm seeking the way to simplify it by creating variable inside the template loop. Is it possible any way?

P.S. creating full-data array out of UsersKeyedObject makes users list non-reactive, so that's bad way.

Some clarifications if you need them:
Mutable UsersKeyedObject

```
{1431535:{name:"John",age:23},253262:{name:"Anna", age:96}}
```

computedUsersAgeSorter

```
[[1431535,23],[253262,96]]
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you have and what you want to list in the UI. Thanks

Comment: This is a proper reason to extract a component.

Comment: Finally I see there's no way to set variable inside the v-for loop. So extracting a child component from parent component looks like best option within the not-so-good reminder. 
It seems that Vue components are not bloating (they're not functions), so child component must be defined before parent, or Uncaught ReferenceError is fired.

Answer (score 1):

You can push each object into an array and use them like this:

Sorting the array ( there is probably a cleaner way to do this ):

```
  computed: {
    sortedArr(){
      const objEntries = Object.entries(this.my_data);
      const merged = objEntries.map(item => {
        return { id : item[0], ...item[1]}
      })
      merged.sort((a,b)=> a.age < b.age)
      
      return merged;
    }
  }
```

Using it within the template:

```
    <div v-for="(item, index) in sortedArr" :key="index">
      <p><span>ID: {{item.id}}</span> <span>Age:{{item.age}}</span></p>
```

https://codepen.io/timfranklin/pen/YzVYQPe

Comment: This is not a desired way, because it tends to recalculate the whole structure after changing a single piece of data in the source. But thanks for code.

Comment: Sure, but you will most likely have reactivity issues if you try to change nested data without replacing the whole object.  Be sure to reference this  to ensure your component will actually update if the source changes. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 1):

I've found this page while looking for the solution, but had to find the answer myself

Say, you want to drastically simplify the code looking like

```
<script setup lang="ts">
/** the generation function, let's say it can't be simplified */
function generateItemFunctionWithLongNameAndManyArguments(id: number, countA: number, countB: number, countC: number, countD: number) {
  return {
    id, a: (id * 1000).toString(countA % 35 + 2),
    b: (id * 1000).toString(countB % 35 + 2),
    c: (id * 1000).toString(countC % 35 + 2),
    d: (id * 1000).toString(countD % 35 + 2),
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div v-for="i of 100">
    {{ generateItemFunctionWithLongNameAndManyArguments(i, i, i, i, i).id }}:
    {{ generateItemFunctionWithLongNameAndManyArguments(i, i, i, i, i).a }}:
    {{ generateItemFunctionWithLongNameAndManyArguments(i, i, i, i, i).b }}:
    {{ generateItemFunctionWithLongNameAndManyArguments(i, i, i, i, i).c }}:
    {{ generateItemFunctionWithLongNameAndManyArguments(i, i, i, i, i).d }}:
  </div>
</template>
```

So you want to cache that thing into a variable
In this case you may use single-item `v-for` in `<template>` tag:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="i of 100">
    <template v-for="item of [generateItemFunctionWithLongNameAndManyArguments(i, i, i, i, i)]">
      {{ item.id }}:
      {{ item.a }}:
      {{ item.b }}:
      {{ item.c }}:
      {{ item.d }}:
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

or even use with destructurizing like

```
<template>
  <div v-for="i of 100">
    <template v-for="{id, a, b, c, d} of [generateItemFunctionWithLongNameAndManyArguments(i, i, i, i, i)]">
      {{ id }}: {{ a }}: {{ b }}: {{ c }}: {{ d }}:
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```